# how to insert dynamic input type file?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

How to insert dynamic input type file?

I have problem to insert dynamic type file into my database.
in my database its work and appear in field, but the value is text "array".

Can you tell me and give me an example code about how to insert dynamic input type file? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

if you wanna add a array into your database, you can use seriliaze() to save.

```
seriliaze($youArrData)
```

if u wanna take this array, you can use unseriliaze() to restore this array from database.

Official Guide :http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php